# Extract 2 parts of a string

Tags: r, regex

Assume I have the following string (filename):

```
a <- "X/ZHEB100/TKN_VAR29380_timely_p1.txt"
```

which consists of several parts (here is given p1)

or another one

```
b <- "X/ZHEB100/ZHN_VAR29380_timely.txt"
```

which consists of only one part (so no need to label any p)

How can I extract the Identifier, which is the three letters before the `VARXXXXX` (so in case one it would be `TKN`, in case two it would be `ZHN`) PLUS the part identifier, if available?

So the result should be:

```
case1 : TKN_p1
case2 : ZHN
```

I know how to extract the first identifier, but I cannot handle the second one at the same time.

My approach so far:

```
sub(".*(.{3})_VAR29380_timely(.{3}).*","\\1\\2", a)
sub(".*(.{3})_VAR29380_timely(.{3}).*","\\1\\2", b)
```

but this adds `.tx` incorrectly in the second case.

Comment: Try `sub("^.*/([A-Z]{3})_[^/_]+_[^/_]+(_[^_./]+)?\\.[^.]*$", "\\1\\2", a)`

Comment: Maybe test first for an identifier, e.g. `stringr::str_match(string, '_p.\\.txt')` and then use two much simpler regexes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that doesn't work for the second case.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/DE0gEe. Do you mean `_VAR29380_timely` are static and always are there inside the string? Then see https://ideone.com/A7ZaJi (`sub("^.*/([A-Z]{3})_VAR\\d+_timely(_[^_.]+)?\\.[^.]*$", "\\1\\2", a)`).

Comment: now it works! Yes these parts are static. You could make an answer out of your comment if you like and explain the regex a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using anchors and matching the last 3 characters right after `timely` without checking what these characters are (`.` matches any character).

I suggest

```
sub("^.*/([A-Z]{3})_VAR\\d+_timely(_[^_.]+)?\\.[^.]*$", "\\1\\2", a)
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*/` - part of string up to and including the last `/`
- `([A-Z]{3})` - 3 ASCII uppercase letters captured into Group 1
- `_VAR\\d+_timely`  - `_VAR` + 1 or more digits + `_timely`
- `(_[^_.]+)?` - an optional Group 2 capturing `_` + 1 or more chars other than `_` and `.`
- `\\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Replacement pattern contains 2 backreferences to both the capturing groups to insert their contents to the replaced string.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/A7ZaJi):

```
a <- "X/ZHEB100/TKN_VAR29380_timely_p1.txt"
a2 <- sub("^.*/([A-Z]{3})_VAR\\d+_timely(_[^_.]+)?\\.[^.]*$", "\\1\\2", a)
a2
[1] "TKN_p1"
b <- "X/ZHEB100/ZHN_VAR29380_timely.txt"
b2 <- sub("^.*/([A-Z]{3})_VAR\\d+_timely(_[^_.]+)?\\.[^.]*$", "\\1\\2", b)
b2
[1] "ZHN"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution, for something different from Wiktor's already working solution:

```
library( magrittr )
data <- c( a, b )
```

First get the "ID" values by splitting on "/", taking the last value, and taking the first 3 characters of that:

```
ID <- strsplit( data, "/" ) %>%
    sapply( tail, n = 1 ) %>%
    substr( 1, 3 )
```

Then get the "part" values by splitting out both "timely" and ".txt", and taking the last element (which may be an empty string):

```
part <- strsplit( data, "timely|.txt" ) %>%
    sapply( tail, n = 1 )
```

Now just paste them together for the result:

```
output <- paste0( ID, part )
output
[1] "TKN_p1" "ZHN"
```

Or, if you'd rather not create the intermediate objects:

```
output <- strsplit( data, "/" ) %>%
    sapply( tail, n = 1 ) %>%
    substr( 1, 3 ) %>%
    paste0( strsplit( data, "timely|.txt" ) %>%
                      sapply( tail, n = 1 ) )
```